# How to use a variable storing an equal sign in an SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a search toolbar on my web page to allow the user to identify what column to search, and what operator to use to search that column. To avoid having a lot of if statements, I want to write the SQL like this:

```
if ($operator == "LIKE") {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` '$operator' '%$search%'";
} else {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` '$operator' '$search'";
}
```

This works fine if the operator is LIKE, but when it is =, it doesn't work.  I've checked the array that is posted to the page, and have confirmed that the array is posting correctly.  How do I make this work when the operator is "=" ?  Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [column] => first_name
    [operator] => =
    [search] => paul
    [page_rows] => 10
)
```

Comment: SQL doesn't use quotes around operators; but if it's data that comes from user input, whitelist it

Comment: simple debug would have solved your problem, even if you don't have a debugging tool, print the query text before running it, have a look at it, and you will probably see the problem with the `'` around the variables

Comment: @simsim Do you have a particular debugging tool you'd recommend?

Comment: @user3865463, here are some tools to debug PHP: [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/).  have a look at [this link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php) for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would run removing `'` around operators:

```
if ($operator == "LIKE") {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` $operator '%$search%'";
} else {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` $operator '$search'";
}
```

but maybe it's better to just use:

```
if ($operator == "LIKE") {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` LIKE '%$search%'";
} else {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `$column` = '$search'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  A follow up question, I'm using a variable for an operator so I can reduce the number of if statements.  So the 'else' would also work for !=, >, <, etc.  Are you recommending against that?  If so, why?

Comment: You should just be sure that you cannot have unexpected value in `$operator` (to avoid sql injection). If so, then I'd say is ok to use the operator variable...

Answer (score 0):

do not use single quotes `'` on `$operater`. it will be better to use `LIKE` or `=` directly.